# Is there any reason why author divides $e$ to show supremum?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am reading a math book... It is written there:

> Example 3: Show by definition: $\inf X=1$ and $\sup X=5$ for $X =\{1;2\} \cup (3;5)$.
> $$
> \begin{multline}
> \sup X = 5 \iff \\ 
> \forall e > 0 \; \exists\,  x_e = \Bigl(5-\dfrac{e}{2} \;\text{for}\; 0 < e < 2 \Bigr) \land (4 \;\text{for}\; \space e \geq 2):  
> \; x_e \in X \;\text{and}\; x_e > 5-e 
> \end{multline}
> $$

Okay, the reason why author enumerates different cases of $x$ so $x>5-e$ for different $e$ is barely, yet logical.

Can someone please tell, is there any reason why author divides $e$ by exactly two and divides at all? Am I missing something? If author had written it as
$$
(5-e \;\text{for}\; 0 < e < 1) 
\land (4 \;\text{for}\; e \geq 1),
$$
would there have been a difference?

Because if there is no reason, after reading the book for a while I am starting to believe in conspirology that it was intended to maximally confuse students that studying are with it.

Comment: Propably, it indeed, makes sense, since if there will not be division, it will not satisfy $x_e>5-e$

Comment: Indeed, the true reason is that you need $x_e > 5-e$. That won't hold without dividing $e$. Although it doesn't matter that by $2$. There's no conspiracy here.

Comment: @freakish, so, there could be also 3 in demominator, and author probably just took the smallest one?

Comment: There could also be $1.5$ in denominator. Anything $>1$ will work. It is common to take $2$, sort of a style that you will see used often, by many authors.

Comment: So the idea is if we take $5-e$ we need $5-e < x_e < 5$ and it's obvious there is one but we haven't actually *defined* it.  When I first did this I'd try things like Let $x_e = 5-0.9\times e$ or Let $e': e > e' > 0$ and let $x_e = 5 -e'$ but .. why not just take a brush and do $x_e = 5 -\frac e2 > 5 -e$.  The choice of $4$ kind of threw my through a loop.  You know, I think the way I'd do this we be. If $e \le 2$ let $x_e$ be any in $(5-e, 5)$ and if $e > 2$ then $x_e$ be anything in $(3,5)$... I guess some authors like things spelled out. (Avoiding illusion of choice and all that).

Comment: @freakish, why there also logical AND, instead of OR?